# How to change title and icon of a terminal program in Gnome 3?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, gnome

I have a couple of terminal based programs which I'll never be able to
leave behind.  When I start them from the command line with something
like

```
gnome-terminal --command foo
```

or when I make a Foo.desktop file and I click on the icon in the
Applications overview, Gnome does the right thing in that it makes a
new terminal window and runs the program within it.  I can even give
the window a distinct title with --title=Foo.  But the *application*
name as Gnome knows it, shown in the top bar, and the icon next to it,
are still just "Terminal" and the generic "prompt" icon.  :-(

Apart from bad aesthetics this also makes it inconvenient to
switch to the window because it gets lumped together in the UI
with all the terminals running shells.  If I were a mouse user (grin)
it would take an extra click to select the window from the group of
terminals - as it is, me being a 90% + keyboard user, I cannot just
enter the overview and type "Foo" because that would start a new one,
not switch to the running one.

So, where does the UI get these bits of information, so I can go there
and change them?  Trying to solve this puzzle I found something
interesting: if I use urxvt instead of gnome-terminal as the emulator,
Gnome displays "rxvt-unicode" as the application name.  Where the hell
does that come from?  The program is named "urxvt" and so is the
window (in the sense of Xwindow resource names), and the window class
is "Urxvt".  So far as I knew "rxvt-unicode" was just a human oriented
nice name of the project, not something the system understood, so
where does Gnome get it?

Comment: Marius, had you read my question carefully, you'd have understood that doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because this is how GNOME Terminal works; it is still one application with many windows. (It's similar to opening multiple web pages in different windows in Firefox.)

Your UX issue is partly addressed by the [Alternate Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) shell extension — although, even without that, the Tab key in the overview does switch between all windows, not just grouped applications.

(FWIW: I'm not sure where `rxvt-unicode` is coming from offhand, but if you run `strings  /usr/bin/urxvt|grep rxvt-unicode`, it does appear in there.)

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling with the stupid web interface for commenting.

Comment: >>
this is how GNOME Terminal works; it is still one application with
many windows. (It's similar to opening multiple web pages in different
windows in Firefox.)
<<

I don't think this is right.  The problem is the same with urxvt, and
urxvt is an old style Xwindow program which knows nothing about
multiple windows or tabs.

Comment: >>
the Tab key in the overview does switch between all windows, not just
grouped applications
<<

Really?  For me, Tab in the overview does nothing at all.  Perhaps you
mean the switcher widget which appears on Window-Tab?

Comment: No, I mean in the overview....

Comment: What version of Fedora / GNOME are you on?

Comment: I should clarify that I place each "task" in a different workspace.  When I place my terminal based apps in the same workspace as the shells, I can indeed switch to them in the overview.  Maybe you have everything in one workspace?

Comment: Ah, yeah, the tab-in-overview does not switch workspaces.

Comment: Ok, I shall look at the AltTab extension.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure where Shell is getting the application name for the title, but hopefully this was at least something :)

Comment: Turns out there is already a UI to do what I want, without any extension; it's just not advertised loudly and maybe not bound to a key.  It's the "Switch windows" action in Settings.  ACKing this answer because it pointed me in the right direction.